# Looking for a fantasy series where magic was powered by light

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I read it back in the early 1990s. The magic was drawn from sunlight and moonlight. Magic drawn from star light was forbidden.  Until, of course, someone challenged that. That’s about all I remember. I think it was a multi book series.

Comment: Somehwere online I read something about magic powered by sunlight, moonlight, or starlight.  But I don't remember where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93904/90s-sci-fi-fantasy-book-series-with-a-girl-who-can-control-fire-main-enemy-is-h/93905#93905 -- I just noticed that the answer posted for that one was never formally accepted, but it was probably correct when it mentioned *Dragon Prince,* first book of a series by Melanie Rawn (two trilogies) set in a world where magic-users are called "sunrunners."

Comment: I think that must be it. Thank you Lorendiac! It's amazing how little I remembered. It

Comment: @Lorendiac OP seems to have confirmed this in an answer below in a new account. Might be worth posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another set of stories that use this concept is Zenna Henderson's Book of the People, and "The People: No Different Flesh"

The people are aliens who have 'gifts', so more Psi, less magic.

One of the gifts is to "Platt Twishers"  This is using mind plus environment to lift and move things.  Almost anyone can use sunlight.  Using moonlight is harder, but has more power.  Darkness and Storm can move mountains.